# Limit of $(x+k)(F(x)-F(x-a)$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: limits, probability-theory, probability-distributions, limits-without-lhopital

I want to show 
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} (x+k)(F(x+c)-F(x)) = 0$$
where $F$ is a cdf of a continuous distribution with finite variance, and $c$ and $k$ are positive constants.

Using the method described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181023/limit-of-x-left1-fx-right-as-x-to-infty), I can show $ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x(F(x+c)-F(x)) = 0$, and $ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} (x+k)(F(x+k+c)-F(x+k)) = 0$, but I can't be certain if my result follows from these. Does it? If not, what are some conditions under which it would?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a general distribution the method you have described is not applicable since $F$ need not even be continuous.

The result is not true in general. You can show that if $F(x)=1-\frac {\ln \, 2} {\ln (1+x)}$ for $x \geq 1$ and $0$ for $x <1$
 the this property is not satisfied.

The result is true if the expectation is finite. This follows from Chebychev's inequálity: $P(X>x) \leq \frac {E|X|I_{\{X>x\}}} x$ for $x >0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. F is actually continuous, I updated the question to reflect that. Also, doesn't the finiteness of the expectation follow from the fact that the variance is finite?